# Outbound E-mail Profile API: Get list of e-mailaddresses

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I'm working on a Java console application that needs to go through all the e-mailaddresses in the frontend database in Tridion Outbound E-mail 2011 and change a certain extended field of that contact.

I've gone through the Subscription API documentation for clues on how to get a listing of all the e-mailaddresses, but I'm getting stuck there. Is there any clean way to do this through the API, without resorting to database queries?

Comment: Have you looked at the AudienceManagerProfileDAO? It has some methods for querying. I don't have any personal experience with it though.

Comment: @Quirijn, I've had a look at that and the ConnectionManager classes. It seems the ConnectionManager class contains the possible queries and stored procedures that the Subscription API needs. It's a bit too sealed to do anything else with those classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to get a list of Contacts using the Subscription API. It is meant primarily for working with single Contacts, who update their profile on your website.

For bulk management of Contacts, you should use Tridion.AudienceManagement.API on your Content Management server instead. The changes will then be synchronized to all of your websites.

You should not change *anything* directly in the database, as you *will* get issues with synchronization.

Comment: Thanks, it seems this is the only road.